# PHP : Optimizing File Parsing

Tags: php, optimization

I have a log file of about 200,000 rows . Each row's format is :

> AAA||BBB|C|DDD||

Now I parse the values using the following parsing loop :

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r');
if($fh === FALSE) {
  return null;
}
$result = array();
while(!feof($fh)) {
  $line = fgets($fh);
  $tokens = explode('||', $line);
  $a = $tokens[0];
  list($b, $c, $d) = explode('|', $tokens[1]);
  // then I can get the values of AAA , BBB , C and DDD and put it into an array
  $result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);
}
```

`$result[$a]` contains all I need, however the parsing time is ~2.1 second. What can I do to reduce parsing speed ?

Comment: Benchmark and profile using tools designed for the task, like xdebug.  This will tell you where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I did. `fgets()` is the bottleneck.

Comment: Use fgetcsv() to read and explode in one go

Comment: Disadvantage of `fgetcsv()` is, I can't check for errors row by row, and ignore / report the problematic line. Once a malformed line is detected, `fgetcsv()` will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers & comments . I did a benchmark of the following functions :

- [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)
- [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
- [stream_get_line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php)
- stream_get_line + str_getcsv
- fgets + str_getcsv

with the following codes ( omitted the while-loop ) :

```
// fgets ( same code in the question )
$tokens = explode('||', $line);
$a = $tokens[0];
list($b, $c, $d) = explode('|', $tokens[1]);
$result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);

// fgetcsv
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
list($a, $nouse1, $b, $c, $d, $nouse2, $nouse3) = fgetcsv($fh, 200, '|');
$result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);

// stream_get_line
$line = stream_get_line($fh, 200, PHP_EOL);
$tokens = explode('||', $line);
if(count($tokens) != 3) {
  continue;
}
$a = $tokens[0];
list($b, $c, $d) = explode('|', $tokens[1]);
$result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);

// stream_get_line + str_getcsv
$line = stream_get_line($fh, 200, PHP_EOL);
list($a, $nouse1, $b, $c, $d, $nouse2, $nouse3) = str_getcsv($line, '|');
$result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);

// fgets + str_getcsv
$line = fgets($fh);
list($a, $nouse1, $b, $c, $d, $nouse2, $nouse3) = str_getcsv($line, '|');
$result[$a] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d);
```

They parse the same text file in same path in same testing machine. The line format is :

> AAA||BBB|C|DDD||

Here is the result (tested 3 times and take average timings) :

- [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) : 3.1452s
- [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) : 4.3895s
- [stream_get_line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) : 3.1956s
- stream_get_line + str_getcsv : 3.7148s
- fgets + str_getcsv : 3.4751s

Unexpectedly, `fgetcsv()` is the slowest. But why ?

*sidenote:* `stream_get_line()` only available in PHP 5.

Answer (score 1):

File parsing in PHP is slow. I did some benchmarking between fgetcsv and a custom csv function a while ago, and fgetcsv was a clear winner (By a factor of around 10 I think).
You should be able to rearrange your code to use fgetcsv, using '|' as your delimiter.

Comment: Disadvantage of `fgetcsv()` is, I can't check for errors row by row, and ignore / report the problematic line. Once a malformed line is detected, `fgetcsv()` will fail.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you could use `fgets()` to read the line, `str_getcsv()` to parse it, and use your own function to parse only error rows. `str_getcsv()` should still parse the line much faster thatn a custom php function.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure how much this will really help, but what about exploding on | and assigning $a = $tokens[0], $b = $tokens[2], etc. You'll reduce your explode calls per iteration by one.

You also could achieve a similar thing by using fgetcsv with '|' as your delimiter. Again, not sure how much that's really going to improve things.

Comment: Interesting. I was skeptical that you'd get much improvement but I definitely wouldn't have expected it to be worse. It must have to do with parsing for the other 'rules' of a csv file, ie, may or may not be wrapped in ' or ". Things like that.